# singleton are creating each time at each launch

Tags: ios, singleton

I'm confused about how to use `singleton` effectively. I want my `singleton` class to behave like `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. But what I've observed is each time it is creating new object and I see a different memory address each time.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];

if(sharedManager.name.length==0) {
sharedManager.name = @"manager";  
    }


return YES;
}



+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;}
```

each time at launch, if clause is executing.

Comment: Of course it is. A singleton only lasts while the app is running. `NSUserDefaults` is no different. If you want the data to survive app runs, you need to persist and restore the data from a file or some other store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not what a `singleton` does.

A `singleton` is an object for which there is only one instance while your application is running. If you call `[MyManager sharedManager]` 10 times in a row, you'll get the same address each time.

Once you quit the application, like any other object the `singleton` is destroyed. Next time you start the application, you'll get a brand new `singleton` being created without any of the old data.

`NSUserDefaults` is able to remember data even after quitting and restarting the application because it is `persisting` that data to disk (i.e. writing a file somewhere.) If you want to have similar behaviour, you'll also need to save you data to a file and read that file on startup.